# It's about foreach and array, details in the post

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So I have this code

```
foreach ($exportQueryResult->deckGroups as $key => $deckGroup) {
   $row['Group name'.$key] = $deckGroup->name;
}
```

which returns me

```
[
    "Group name0" => "name"
    "Group name1" => "Hakuna MATATA *"
]
```

is there a possibility to return something like that:

```
[
    "Group name" => "name"
    "Group name" => "Hakuna MATATA *"
]
```

I know it's not really explicit but it's the best i could say :)

Comment: `$row['Group name'] = $deckGroup->name;` ?

Comment: You can't have the same index in an array more than once.

Comment: it's a foreach so this return me just the last $deckGroup->name, which is HAKUNA MATATA *

Comment: No there isn't. An array can only have one key with the same name. Duplicated keys will be overwritten

Comment: @Andreas okay, thanks

Comment: You could do `$row['Group name'][] = ` not exactly the same.

Comment: What you can do is `$row['group name'][] = ...` this will make it multidimensional and associative

Comment: Would some sort of array merge accomplish this? Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Cause Array doesn't support same index name. Array index name always be unique. If you try to like a['value'] = 5 and again a['value'] = 10 then it will show the result like this a = ['value'= 10]

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is impossible because keys in associative arrays are unique.

The closest you can get to what you think you want would be an associative array for which the value is an array filled with the values that get filed under that key.

For example:

```
$row['Group name'] = [];
foreach ($exportQueryResult->deckGroups as $key => $deckGroup) {
    array_push($row['Group name'], $deckGroup->name);
}
```

This should result in something like:

```
[
    "Group name" => ["name", "Hakuna MATATA *"]
]
```